# Repackage 3rd party libraries as NuGet package

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I am using a 3rd party library which supports .NET Core, but not .NET Standard. They provide separate binary SDKs for each platform they support; win-x86, linux-x64, etc. For each platform there is a CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll, and a coolsdk.dll/so/dylib. The `CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll` files are indeed different for each platform - they're all exactly the same size, but have different SHA hashes.

For my own sanity I'd like to repackage all this as a single `.nupkg` using runtime identifiers to pull in the right stuff for a given platform, so that I can build for Windows, docker, etc without having to swap binaries around. I have a project file like so:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>CoolSdk.NetStandard</PackageId>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
    <RootNamespace>coolsdk</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>coolsdk</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/win-x64/native/coolsdk.dll" Update="windows/x64/coolsdk.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/win-x64/lib/netcore/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll" Update="windows/x64/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>

    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/linux-x64/native/libcoolsdk.so" Update="linux/x64/libcoolsdk.so">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netcore/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll" Update="linux/x64/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This produces a `.nupkg` that appears to have everything I need, but consuming projects don't actually get a reference to the CoolSdkDotNetCore assembly. In the bin folder, I see a runtimes folder with the `native` components, but no `lib` folders (the lib folders are definitely present in the actual nupkg).

What am I missing here? Do I need to go back and write a `nuspec` myself instead of trying to use a `csproj` to generate it all for me, or is there some other trick I can use?

---

edit:

Changing the library paths above from `runtimes/<rid>/lib/netcore` to `runtimes/<rid>/netcoreapp` allows the lib folders to be copied to the bin folder in a consuming project, but I'm still not able to actually reference the assembly. Manually adding a reference to `CoolSdkDotNetCore` like:

```
<Reference Include="CoolSdkDotNetCore">
  <HintPath>CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Generates `MSB3245 - Could not resolve this reference...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to include a single copy of the .NET Core assembly as a "ref". Which one doesn't really matter - this assembly will never be run, only loaded by the IDE and at compile time. At runtime, the correct assembly will be loaded from the `runtimes` folder. As a final gotcha, nuget will not pack the same file twice; if you have two or more items in the item group with the same value for the `Update` key, only the last one will actually get added to the final `.nupkg`. So, picking at random I made a copy of the windows/x64 dll in the root of my project, and updated my csproj thusly:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>CoolSdk.NetStandard</PackageId>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
    <RootNamespace>coolsdk</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>coolsdk</AssemblyName>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="ref/netcoreapp2.1/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll" Update="CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>

    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/win-x64/native/coolsdk.dll" Update="windows/x64/coolsdk.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/win-x64/lib/netcore/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll" Update="windows/x64/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>

    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/linux-x64/native/libcoolsdk.so" Update="linux/x64/libcoolsdk.so">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netcore/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll" Update="linux/x64/CoolSdkDotNetCore.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```